# Octave columns from txt file to vectors

Tags: vector, octave

I am trying to convert data that I have in my .txt file( few lines below):

> nodeID, ts, in_pkts, out_pkts, in_links, out_links
>
> 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0
>
> 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0
>
> 1, 3, 1, 13, 0, 0
>
> 1, 4, 1, 8, 0, 0
>
> 1, 5, 1, 2, 0, 0

I would like to get values from the secon column as x, and third as y and then use
`plot(x,y)`
to get a figure.
I thought about using the `read` function but how could I get just second and third column.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25214848/901925
has a more complicated case of reading a text file with Octave.

I think your case can be handled with `csvread` (among others).  It will give you a matrix, from which you can select the desired columns.

```
octave:3> x=csvread('stack25230911.txt')
x =

    0    0    0    0    0    0
    1    1    0    0    0    0
    1    2    2    2    0    0
    1    3    1   13    0    0
    1    4    1    8    0    0
    1    5    1    2    0    0

octave:8> x=M(2:end,2);
octave:9> y=M(2:end,3);
octave:10> plot(x,y)
```